# Poker Bank application

Tags: java, playing-cards

For playing a Poker tournament, I wanted to create an application which should calculate the pot and the money of all players at every time.

`PokerBank` class:

```
public class PokerBank {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("---------------Spiel Beginnen----------------");

    try {
        request();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Fehler bei der Eingabe");
    }
    String[] playernames = new String[numberOfPlayers];
    try {
        playernames = requestNames();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Fehler bei der Names Eingabe");
    }

    Player[] players = new Player[playernames.length];
    players = requestPlayers(playernames);

    // Initialisation of the Players
    double bigBlind = initialBigblind;




    // first call of the play with the Pot of zero and the dealer Offset Zero
    boolean round = true;
    // The firts round is set as true becouse it now it is the first round
    playRound(bigBlind, players, round, 0,0);

}
public static int numberOfPlayers;
public static double initialBigblind;
public static double initialCapital;

/**
 * Method to request the main Settings
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void request() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Wie viele Spieler machen mit?");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    numberOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println("Wie hoch ist der Anfangsbetrag jedes Spielers?");
    initialCapital = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println("Wie hoch ist der Big Blind?");
    initialBigblind = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());

}

/**
 * 
 * Method to play the round
 * @param BigBlind the Big blind of the game
 * @param players The Players in form of an Array
 * @param NewRound boolean if it is a new round
 * @param Pot Potsize 
 * @param DealerOffSet to store the position of the dealer
 */
public static void playRound(double BigBlind, Player[] players, boolean NewRound, double Pot, int DealerOffSet) {
    double currentValueOfBet;
    double pot = Pot;
    int dealerOff;
    // if the DealerOffset would be out of the player array bound it will be setted as 0
    // this provides that the "Dealer Button" goes arround
    if(DealerOffSet<players.length-1){
        dealerOff =DealerOffSet;
    }else{dealerOff=0;}

    // if it is a new round e.g.(before the Flop), the big and Small blind will be setted 
    if (NewRound) {
        currentValueOfBet = BigBlind;
        System.out.println("Dealer in dieser runde ist "+players[dealerOff].getName());
    System.out.println("Small Blind von "+BigBlind/2+" zahlt "+players[dealerOff+1].getName());
    players[dealerOff+1].makeStake(BigBlind/2);
    pot+=BigBlind/2;
    players[dealerOff+1].setBlind();
    // to prevent an array out of bound Exception becouse there are just two pepole left in the game
    // there is a if Statement to set another player as the dealer and the BigBlind
    if (players.length<2){
        System.out.println("Den Big Blind von "+BigBlind+" zahlt "+players[dealerOff].getName());
    players[dealerOff].makeStake(BigBlind);
    pot+=BigBlind;
    players[dealerOff].setBlind();
    }else{
    System.out.println("Den Big Blind von "+BigBlind+" zahlt "+players[dealerOff+2].getName());
    players[dealerOff+2].makeStake(BigBlind);
    pot+=BigBlind;
    players[dealerOff+2].setBlind();
    }

    // if it is not the first round(after the flop or someone has risen then the Value of a bet is intitialized as zero
    } else {
        currentValueOfBet = 0;
    }

    // the loop over all players to ask anyone of them what for an action he wants to do
    for (Player player : players) {
        if (!player.getIN()) {
            System.out.println("Spieler " + player.getName() + " ist bereits raus");
        } else {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            char choice = 0;
            System.out.println(player.getName() + " Ihre Wahl?");
            try {
                choice = reader.readLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Keine Gültige Wahl");
            }
            switch (choice) {
                // Choice for call or check
                case 'c':
                    if (player.getStake() <= currentValueOfBet) {
                        pot+=currentValueOfBet-player.getStake();
                        player.makeStake(currentValueOfBet - player.getStake());


                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Sie können nicht callen, da ihr bisheriger einsatz schon höher ist.");
                    }
                    break;
                    // choice for raise
                case 'r':
                    System.out.println("wie viel wollen Sie Setzen?");
                    double raise = 0;
                    try {
                        raise = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Dies war keine gültige Zahl");
                    }
                    player.makeStake(raise);
                    currentValueOfBet = raise;
                    pot = pot + raise;
                    break;
                    // chase for fold
                case 'f':
                    player.resetStake();
                    player.setOUT();
            }
        }
    }
    for (Player player : players) {

        player.Ausgabe();
        player.resetStake();
        player.resetblind();
    }
    System.out.println("Der Pot steht bei " + pot);

    int numOfIN = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int numOfLost = 0;
    for (int test = 0; test < players.length; test++) {
        if (players[test].getIN()) {
            numOfIN++;
            index = test;
        }

    }
    for (Player player : players) {
        if (player.getMoney() <= 0) {
            numOfLost += 1;
        }
    }
    // if only one is left then he is the winner of the  pot
    if (numOfIN == 1) {
        players[index].earnPot(pot);
        for (Player player : players) {
            player.setIN();
            player.Ausgabe();
        }
        playRound(BigBlind, players, true, 0,dealerOff+1);

    }
    // Next Round without the ones who folded
    if (numOfLost >= players.length - 1) {
        System.out.println("Runde ist Beendet");

        // the big Blind stays the same 
        playRound(BigBlind, players, false, pot,dealerOff+1);

    } else {
        // If the 
        playRound(BigBlind, players, false, pot,dealerOff);
    }

}

/**
 * Method to request the names of the players and stores it in an array
 * @return array with Playernames
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private static String[] requestNames() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] playernames = new String[numberOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < playernames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name von Spieler " + (i + 1));

        String name;
        name = (reader.readLine());
        playernames[i] = name;
    }
    return playernames;
}

/**
 * Method to initialize all Player objects
 * @param playernames
 * @return Players as an array of Player[]
 */
private static Player[] requestPlayers(String[] playernames) {

    Player[] players = new Player[playernames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < playernames.length; i++) {

        players[i] = new Player(initialCapital, playernames[i]);
    }
    return players;

}




}
```

`Player` class:

```
public class Player {
double money;
String name;
double currentstake=0;
boolean in=true;
boolean Blind=false;


public Player(double initialCapital, String name){
   this.money = initialCapital;
    this.name=name;

}
/**
 * sets the Stake to zero
 */
public void resetStake(){
    currentstake=0;
}
/**
 * set the Blind to true
 */
public void setBlind(){
    Blind = true;
}
/**
 * set the blind to false
 */
public void resetblind(){
    Blind=false;
}
/**
 * request what for a Blind status the player has
 * @return Blind status
 */
public boolean isBlind(){
    return Blind;
}
/**
 * request how much money the player has
 * @return ammount of money
 */
public double getMoney(){
    return money;
}
/**
 * gives out if the player is still in the game
 * @return Status if the player is in or out of the game
 */
public boolean getIN(){
    return in;
}
/**
 * set the player out of the game
 */
public void setOUT(){
    in=false;
}
/**
 * set the player in the game
 */
public void setIN(){
    in=true;
}
/**
 * sets a new Stake to raise or to call
 * @param stake the stake which the player make
 */
public void makeStake(double stake){
    currentstake=currentstake +stake;
    money=money-stake;
}
/**
 * shows the current Stake
 * @return the current Stake which the player made
 */
public double getStake(){
    return currentstake;
}

/**
 * method to buy in
 * @param ammount of money to buy in
 */
public void earnPot(double ammount){
    money +=ammount;
}
/**
 * returns the Name of the Player
 * @return 
 */
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

/**
 * Gives out the Status of the player
 */
public void Ausgabe(){


   System.out.println(name+"\n"+money+"\n"+"-------------------");

}



}
```

As you can see, my problem is that the code is very long. I would like to know if there is a way to write the same but in a shorter way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Language

The I/O of your programm is german. That's okay, but not so good if you post this in an mainly English Q&A forum. I'm german too ;)

## Main method

```
Player[] players = new Player[playernames.length];
players=requestPlayers(playernames);
double bigBlind = initialBigBlind;
boolean round = true;
playRound(bigBlind,requestPlayers(playernames),round,0,0);
```

Why don't shorten to:

```
 playRound(initialBigBlind,new Player[playernames.length],0,0);
```

## `request` function

Use `java.util.Scanner`. Also what is if I just input

```
Wie viele Spieler machen mit?
> foo
```

Probably not what you want. And you need that code repeatedly. So make an extra function:

```
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
public int readInt(String message){
  while(!s.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println(message);
  }
  return s.nextInt();
}
public double readDouble(String message){
  while(!s.hasNextDouble()){
    System.out.println(message);
  }
  return s.nextDouble();
}
```

Now the `foo` as input doesn't works any more to crash your programm.

```
Wie viele Spieler machen mit?
> foo
Wie viele Spieler machen mit?
> 5
...
```

## `playRound` function

Messy. Just messy and totally overloaded. And recursive. Clean up a little bit and think about a loop. And renaming the whole thing. Sorry, but I can't give you any specific advise, I don't know Poker good enough to see any logic. That may isn't connected too your code-style. :(

## OOP

Java is for object-oriented-programming. If you want to use only functions then go and use Python. No offense to Python but it's definitely not normal Java to put everything (except the Player) into static context. <s>Maybe</s> At least create an class.

```
public class PokerGame{
  //...
}
```

## `Player` class

```
public void setIN(){//...
public void setOUT(){//...
```

Why don't just use one method

```
public boolean setIn(boolean in){
  boolean old = this.in;
  this.in = in;
  return old;
}
```

Ausgabe?!?!?!

```
public void Ausgabe(){/...
```

Not pretty English. Also there is a toString() method.

```
@Override
public void toString(){
  return name+"\n"+money+"\n"+"-------------------"); 
}
```

And then use `System.out.println(player);` instead `player.Ausgabe();`

Sorry If I sound rude sometimes. I don't mean so I'm just not so good in English and this sounds fairly aggressive to me. I don't want to be rude.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! For the record, as long as the question is adequately explained in English, it's fine. I much prefer to review real code in its original language than an English version that has been poorly translated just for the sake of posting a question in English. (And I'm not German.)